# Conditionally return JSON or HTML response from Django django-rest-framework's view

Tags: python, html, json, django, django-rest-framework

How can you conditionally return a JSON or HTML response from Django django-rest-framework's view?

1. `djangorestframework` == 2.3.10
2. My `settings.py`:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'PAGINATE_BY': 10,
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    )
}
```

3. In my `url.py`, I added this as the last line:

```py
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns, allowed=['json', 'html'])
```

4. My view is something like:

```
def myview(request, id, format='json'):
    if format == 'json' or format is None:
        return Response(my_dict, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(my_dict, template_name='myhtml.html')
```

Everything works OK, if I explicitly use `.html` or `.json`  `format_prefix` in the url request. But it gives me the following error if I don't specify any format.

> ImproperlyConfigured at /objects/29 
> Returned a template response with no `template_name` attribute set on
> either the view or response 
> Request Method: GET 
> Request URL: localhost:8000/objects/29 
> Django Version: 1.7 
> Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured 
> Exception Value: Returned a template response with no `template_name`
> attribute set on either the view or response 
> Exception Location: D:\WORKSPACE\user...\lib\site-

I also tried:

```
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns, allowed=['json', 'html', 'None'])
```

But it doesn't seem to work either.

Could someone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
class MyView(ListAPIView):
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = SomerSerializer([]).data
        if request.accepted_renderer.format == 'html':
            return Response(data, template_name='blah.html')

        return Response(data)
```

FYI I've gotten this error before, but it wasn't because it was configured properly - it was because some unrelated code right before it errored out - so look for anything else that might be failing. Also note that your 'else' is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

After research this **worked** for me
Below django view acts as **template renderer** and **json renderer**

*views.py*

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, renderer_classes
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


@api_view(['GET','POST'])
@renderer_classes([JSONRenderer,TemplateHTMLRenderer])
def myview(request, id, format='json'):
        if format == 'json' or format is None:
            return JsonResponse(my_dict, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return render(request,'template_name.html',{"context":my_dict})
```

*settings.py*

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',        
    'rest_framework.renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer',
    ),
}
```

The above view will act like both **Json renderer** and **Template renderer**.
Based on the condition you can see the behavior.